# How to re-partition pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

```
data.rdd.getNumPartitions() # output 2456
```

Then I do
    `data.rdd.repartition(3000)` 
But
    `data.rdd.getNumPartitions()` # output is still 2456

How to change number of partitions. One approach can be first convert DF into rdd,repartition it and then convert rdd back to DF. But this takes a lot of time.
Also does increasing number of partitions make operations more distributed and so more fast?
Thanks

Comment: You should not repartition the underlying rdd.  Use df.repartition().  Also, it does not change the rdd itself in data, only the newly returned dataframe object,

Comment: @MichelLemay Thanks. How to check if number of partitions has changed?

Comment: Please try: `data.rdd.repartition(3000).getNumPartitions()`. You have to chain the operations. Spark chains all the operations and does not execute until you explicitly call an operation like `.collect()`, `.count()` etc.

Comment: RDDs and DFs are immutable, so just running `data.rdd.repartition(n)` doesn't alter the partitioning of `data` -- you'd need to save it to a new df.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check the number of partitions:

```
data.rdd.partitions.size
```

To change the number of partitions:

```
newDF = data.repartition(3000)
```

You can check the number of partitions:

```
newDF.rdd.partitions.size
```

Beware of data shuffle when repartitionning and this is expensive.  Take a look at `coalesce` if needed.

Comment: Thanks. This works. As per my second question, does more partitions increase operation speed. I tried that but didnt see any improvement. Also is there any way to decide the best number of partitions.

Comment: The right number of partitions is always dependent on the problem at hands.  However, I found few rules of thumb that guide my decisions.  When the problem is sufficiently small and can fit in memory, I usually take a small multiple of the number of cores (something like 2 to 5 times spark.defaultparalellism).  However this becomes impractical when the problem is very large and partitions too big.  At the other end of the spectrum, spark start to become inefficient when you have thousands of partitions on a small cluster.

Comment: Also keep in mind that some operations change the number of partitions automatically.  You have to keep an eye on this.  Another thing to keep in mind is to force the use of a hash partitionner to physically shuffle records closer together when joining for instance.  You will need to have a good understanding of partitions if you want to build efficient spark programs.

Comment: ...Thanks for the details. Would you suggest some resources(books/links) for learning more about pyspark advanced topics like partitioning?

Comment: Getting `'RDD' object has no attribute 'partitions'` from the `df.rdd.partitions.size` call attempt…

Answer (score 13):

```
print df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
# 1


df.repartition(5)
print df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
# 1


df = df.repartition(5)
print df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
# 5
```

see **Spark: The definitive Guide chapter 5- Basic Structure Operations**
ISBN-13: 978-1491912218
ISBN-10: 1491912219

Answer (score 8):

If you want to **increase** the number of partitions, you can use `repartition()`:

```
data = data.repartition(3000)
```

---

If you want to **decrease** the number of partitions, I would advise you to use `coalesce()`, that avoids full shuffle:

> Useful for running operations more efficiently after filtering down a large
> dataset.

```
data = data.coalesce(10)
```

---

**For more details check the article [How to efficiently re-partition Spark DataFrames](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-efficiently-re-partition-spark-dataframes-c036e8261418)**